# How do I solve for a variable inside of a natural log?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

$$e^{A+B*\ln(x)}=m*e^{C+D*\ln(x)}+n,\qquad x \gt 0$$

I'm trying to solve for x in the equation above, but I am not sure where to even begin.  If I take the natural log of both sides, I wind up with

$$A+B*\ln(x)=\ln(m*e^{C+D*\ln(x)}+n)$$

which is no nearer to solving it, and I don't know what to do next.  I don't know of any natural log properties that would be applicable.

Is this equation possible to solve for x?  If so, what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Use exponent properties: $$e^{A+B}=e^Ae^B\\(e^A)^B=e^{AB}\\e^{\ln(x)}=x$$definition of logarithm on the last one.

Comment: Is the +$n$ part of the exponent or is it not? By the way you have written, it looks as though it is not part of the exponent.

Comment: Do you have specific values for $B$ or $D$? Or do you know if they are integers?

Comment: A, B, C, D, n, and m are all known and are not integers. n is not part of the exponent which is the main issue when trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks @SimpleArt.  I feel pretty dumb that I didn't think of that.. got hung up on the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:
$$e^{A + B\ln(x)} = e^Ae^{\ln(x^B)} =e^Ax^B$$
Applying that everywhere, we can simplify down to:
$$e^Ax^B = me^Cx^D + n$$
As we see, we have a polynomial of degree B or D, whichever is higher. A solution to this depends on the value of B, D and n. There is no elementary solution for any B, D and n.

Comment: I think at the end you meant for general $B$, $D$, and $n$. As for small enough $B$ and $D$, we have possible solutions.

Comment: Yeah. Replace "any" with "all" or "general". Said it without thinking.

Comment: Ding ding, we have a winner.  I feel dumb for not thinking to use exponent properties.  Thanks @kaynex!  Now to plug in some number and see how well it turns out.

Comment: Also, sorry I can't upvote.  I've got the rep of a street bum.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first part of this is to see if you can't pull the $x$ from the exponent.

You will need to know how to split this down to only the part you are interested in: $e^{\ln(x)}$ after that you might be in a better spot to solve your problem. (though given how general it is you might still experience some difficulty!)

Comment: This seems more fitting to be a comment.