# How do I solve for a variable inside of a natural log? Part II

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Several weeks ago, I posted [a question regarding the equation below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008577/how-do-i-solve-for-a-variable-inside-of-a-natural-log) and received several very helpful responses.


$$e^{A+B*\ln(x)}=m*e^{C+D*\ln(x)}+n,\qquad x \gt 0$$

Since then, I've had to expand the equation out to include additional log terms shown below.


$$e^{A1+B1*\ln(x)+C1*\ln(x)^2+D1*\ln(x)^3+E1*\ln^4(x)}=m*e^{A2+B2*\ln(x)+C2*\ln(x)^2+D2*\ln(x)^3+E2*\ln^4(x)}+n,\qquad x \gt 0$$

A1, A2, B1, B2, ..., m, and n are all known and x > 0.  I would like solve that equation for x.  Using log and exponential properties, I can "simplify" to the below equation.


$$e^{A1}x^{B1+C1*\ln(x)+D1*\ln^2(x)+E1*\ln^3(x)}=m*e^{A2}x^{B2+C2*\ln(x)+D2*\ln^2(x)+E2*\ln^3(x)}+n,\qquad x \gt 0$$

Is this possible to solve for x?  If so, what's the best way to approach it?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell us something about the variables?

Comment: i think a numerical way is the best

Comment: The variables A1, A2, B1, B2, ..., m and n can be negative or positive but are small (less than 10).  Not sure if that helps..